# why for loop doesn't raise "argument too long" error?

Tags: shell

I found that this would raise the "argument too long" error:

```
ls *.*
```

And this would not raise it:

```
for file in *.*
do
    echo $file
done
```

Why?

Comment: Did you use the same shell in both experiments? Perhaps `/bin/bash` vs. `/bin/sh` (which is perhaps a link to dash)?

Comment: Yes, I made the experiment with 10000 files with filename which are quite long. "ls *" failed and "for f in *" succeeded.

Answer (score 15):

The “argument too long” error is `E2BIG`, raised by the [`execve`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execve.html) system call if the total size of the arguments (plus the environment, on some systems) is too large. The `execve` call is the one that starts external processes, specifically loading a different executable file (there's a different call, [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html), for running a separate process whose code is still from the same executable file). The `for` loop is an internal shell construct, so it doesn't involve calling `execve`. The command `ls *.*` raises the error not when the glob is expanded but when `ls` is called.

`execve` fails with the error `E2BIG` when the total size of the arguments to the command is larger than the `ARG_MAX` [limit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html). You can see the value of this limit on your system with the command `getconf ARG_MAX`. (It's possible that you can go over this limit if you have enough memory; keeping under `ARG_MAX` guarantees that `execve` will work as long as no unrelated error occurs.)

Comment: and why did shell not having an limit?

Comment: @gunbuster363 The `execve` limit is enforced by the kernel, it puts limits because the arguments need to be copied via kernel memory at one point and user processes can't be allowed to request an arbitrary amount of shell memory. Inside the shell, there's no reason to have any limit, anything that fits in virtual memory is fine.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that in the first example `ls` is executed from `bash` through a `fork`/`exec` pair system call, in the second one, all the working is internal to `bash`.

The `exec` call has limits, the internal working of `bash` instead has not (or better, has different limits that have nothing to do with `exec`, perhaps the amount of available memory).

Comment: You can find the limit to `exec` in `/usr/include/linux/limits.h` usually, defined as `ARG_MAX`.

Comment: If we use the shell for loop, do you think a big list of item will consume all the RAM?

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  It isn't 'internal' it is just that the limits for arguments and commands are different.

Answer (score 5):

Because in the case of `ls` it is an argument, and the number of arguments is limited.

In case of the `for` cycle, it is just a list of items. There are no limits (as far as I'm aware) for that.

Comment: There is definitely a limit for the shell expansion. It is very much related to how much RAM you have available .. Try this; my 4GB RAM system blows a gasket at about 15.2 million 8-byte args: `for i in {00000001..20000000} ;do ((10#$i==1)) && break; done`

Comment: @fred I didn't really think that mentioning RAM as a limit is needed.

Comment: It may not be needed, but that is the nature of comments.. someone may find it interesting, or even of value.

Comment: @fred: actually yes, if expanding very large arguments was a common problem, it would be possible to implement it without keeping everything in memory.