# Converting multiple image files from JPEG to PDF format

Tags: command-line, wildcards, conversion, imagemagick

I want to convert some files from jpeg to pdf. I am using following command.

```
$ convert image1.jpg image1.pdf
```

But I have 100 images. How should I convert all of them to corresponding pdfs?

I tried

```
$ convert image*.jpg image*.pdf
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Related: [How to generate a PDF from a series of images?](http://superuser.com/q/687849/87805) at superuser SE

Comment: See also: [AskUbuntu: Create a single pdf from multiple text, images or pdf files](https://askubuntu.com/q/303849/327339). If you'd also like your resulting PDF to be searchable via OCR (Optical Character Recognition) on the text in the input images, use [my `pdf2searchablepdf` tool I describe here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385947/327339), which can also convert an entire directory of images into a single, searchable PDF.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In bash:

```
for f in *.jpg; do
  convert ./"$f" ./"${f%.jpg}.pdf"
done
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you prepend "./" to the args of convert? Is it a general good practice?

Comment: @rahmu: yes, it is a good practice, because filename beginning with `-` give problems, otherwise.

Comment: This works, but `mogrify` is a lot less typing.  See my answer.

Comment: +1 because this is technically correct and avoids bash pitfalls, but -1 because mogrify is the Imagemagick way to batch convert images. So no vote from me.

Comment: @aculich: thank you for your downvote, but you did a wrong consideration, see [why for loop doesn't raise “argument too long” error?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20681/why-for-loop-doesnt-raise-argument-too-long-error).

Comment: @enzotib ah, thanks for pointing that out. I was not aware that it behaved differently in a for loop. I have removed my erroneous comment, but that was not the only reason I down-voted. The `mogrify` command [as cjm suggests](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29875/11052) is much simpler and `find` is more versatile since it can handle directory hierarchies (you can do recursive globbing with `**/*.jpg` in zsh, but that is shell-specific, whereas `find` is not) and it is easy to make `find` case-insensitive with `-iname` instead of `-name`, which is harder to do and shell-specific for globbing.

Comment: @enzotib Also with `find` you do not have problems with filenames that begin with `-`, so there is no need for adding `./` like you must with the shell for loop.

Comment: @jiggunjer it will not let me remove my old downvote because the post has already been edited. my vote was a technical vote based on incorrect assumption about * on my part, not a political vote.

Comment: Using ImageMagick for this results in generation loss and poor performance. img2pdf elsewhere on this page avoids those problems.

Comment: @RobertFleming: the question was not on the choice of the tool, but on the automatic management of a lot of files, so I used the same tool ("convert") proposed in the question and concentrate on the scripting.

Answer (score 66):

You can use the [`mogrify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) command for this.  Normally, it modifies files in-place, but when converting formats, it writes a new file (just changing the extension to match the new format).  Thus:

```
mogrify -format pdf -- *.jpg
```

(Like enzotib's `./*.jpg`, the `--` prevents any strange filenames from being interpreted as switches.  Most commands recognize `--` to mean "stop looking for options at this point".)

Comment: +1, my answer was only about bash, don't know well ImageMagick.

Comment: Good idea to use `mogrify` instead of `convert`. This will work for 100 files, but using globbing with `*.jpg` does not scale to thousands of files; that can be done by combining the command in a [simple one-liner with `find`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30420/11052).

Comment: How to convert *both* `*.jpg` and `*.png` files to a single `*.pdf`? Note that they are numbered files (e.g., `1.jpg 2.png 3.png 4.jpg`) and that order should be maintained/preserved in the pdf output.

Comment: as a workaround: converting all `*.jpg`'s into `*.png`'s in step one, and performing the equivalent of your answer in step 2...

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315770/how-to-convert-all-files-in-different-formats-in-given-folder-to-different-fil

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty, that's a new question, not a comment.  Ask it.

Comment: Using ImageMagick for this results in generation loss and poor performance. img2pdf elsewhere on this page avoids those problems.

Comment: -1 `mogrify mogrify: Unrecognized option (--).`

Comment: Any way to do it recursively?

Comment: This gives me: `mogrify-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.` On Devuan Beowulf.

Answer (score 26):

faster but unusual syntax:

```
parallel convert '{} {.}.pdf' ::: *.jpg
```

Runs in parallel (using https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). I haven't noticed any multi-threading in `convert` yet, which would limit the effective parallelization. If that is your concern, see in the comment below for a method to ensure no multi-threading occurs.

Comment: This way is full of win.  It auto assess core count and runs that many tasks!

Comment: This method is THE fastest of all.

Comment: parallel is power, parallel combined with imagemagick is superpower. I like superpower.

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but new (possibly not when this answer was written) versions of ImageMagick are multi-threaded, and will interact badly if run in parallel.  This can be disabled (if using application-level parallelization such as with GNU `parallel`) by setting the environment variable `MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1`.

Comment: Using ImageMagick for this results in generation loss and poor performance. img2pdf elsewhere on this page avoids those problems.

Comment: Interesting project, Robert, thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 26):

https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf

In all of the proposed solutions involving ImageMagick, the JPEG data gets fully decoded and re-encoded. This results in [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss), as well as performance "ten to hundred" times worse than `img2pdf`.

Available in Debian since Debian 9 (stretch) and Ubuntu since 16.04 (xenial). Also can be installed with `pip img2pdf` provided you have dependencies (e.g. `apt-get install python python-pil python-setuptools libjpeg-dev` or `yum install python python-pillow python-setuptools`).

Comment: is right. You can test that a roundtrip changes a JPEG file with commands like `convert some.jpg -format pdf -compress jpeg generated.pdf ; pdfimages -j generated.pdf generated.pdf ; diff -sq some.jpg generated.pdf-000.jpg`. IMHO this answer deserves more upvotes. Indeed, `convert` fails here, `img2pdf` passes such a test and even includes many options to set picture size, page size, etc to finetune the generated pdf to your needs.

Comment: `img2pdf` is available in Ubuntu 16.04 regular repositories, no need for manual operations with `pip` there, and you keep the benefit of updates.

Comment: At the time the question was asked (and answer accepted) img2pdf did not exist. But nowdays img2pdf is clearly a better answer.

Comment: `img2pdf` is an order of magnitude  better than `convert`

Answer (score 14):

Here is a way that combines the best of the above suggestions into a simple, efficient, robust command line:

```
find /path/to/files -iname '*.jpg' -exec mogrify -format pdf {} +
```

It works fine with filenames that begin with a `-` or contain spaces. Note the use of `-iname` which is the *case-insensitive* version of `-name` so it will work on `.JPG` just as well as `.jpg`.

This uses `find` to get the file list instead of shell globbing with the `*.jpg` wildcard which can result in an ['Argument list too long' error](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#Argument-list-too-long) on some systems. Though as @enzotib points in a comment, behavior of using [globbing in a for loop is different than for a command's arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20681/why-for-loop-doesnt-raise-argument-too-long-error).

Also, `find` will handle subdirectories, whereas shell globbing will not unless you happen to have shell-specific features like the `**/*jpg` recursive globbing syntax in zsh.

**EDIT:** I thought I would add another useful feature of `find` that I thought of after reading a comment by [@IlmariKaronen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29891/11052) about re-running the command and only converting files that have changed since the first run.

On the first pass you can `touch` a timestamp file after the convert is finished.

```
find /path/to/files -iname '*.jpg' -exec mogrify -format pdf {} +; touch timestamp
```

Then add `-newer timestamp` to the `find` expression to operate on the subset of files whose last-modified time is newer than the timestamp file. Continue updating the timestamp file after each run.

```
find /path/to/files -iname '*.jpg' -newer timestamp -exec mogrify -format pdf {} +; touch timestamp
```

This is an easy way to avoid having to resort to a Makefile (unless you're already using one) and it is another good reason why it is worth using `find` whenever possible... it has versatile expressiveness while remaining concise.

Comment: Using ImageMagick for this results in generation loss and poor performance. img2pdf elsewhere on this page avoids those problems.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with `convert` directly. This is to be found at the bottom of ImageMagicks Site about [Command Line Processing](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php).

```
convert *.jpg +adjoin page-%d.pdf
```

Comment: or `convert *.jpg -adjoin output.pdf` for a combined pdf

Comment: Using ImageMagick for this results in generation loss and poor performance. img2pdf elsewhere on this page avoids those problems.

Answer (score 8):

I've used the following makefile for something similar:

```
SVG = $(wildcard origs/*.svg)
PNG = $(patsubst origs/%.svg,%.png,$(SVG))

all: $(PNG)

%.png: origs/%.svg
    convert -resize "64x" $< $@


clean: 
    rm $(PNG)
```

Now I can just run `make` and I get png files for every svg file that lies around.

**Edit**

As requested:

- wildcards generates a list of all svgs in origs/
- pathsubst takes this list and produces a list of png file names (different folder and extension. Example: `origs/foo.svg` becomes `foo.png`)
- Rule 1: `all: $(PNG)` defines, that the target "all" depends on all PNGs
- Rule 2: `%.png: origs/%.svg` defines, thethe file $X.png depends on origs/$X.svg and can be generated by calling `convert ... $< $@`.

  - `$<` is the dependency and and
  - `$@` is the target name
- RUle 3: is just for cleaning up

Comment: For a one-off task, creating a Makefile is probably overkill, but if you ever plan to change some of the PDFs, typing `make` again will reconvert those, and _only_ those, PDFs which have changed.

Comment: Would you mind to explain what wildcard, origs, patsubst is, how $ and % are interpreted and $< $@? The rest is easy to understand. :)

Comment: Resorting to `make` seems a little over-complicated when a [simple one-liner](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30420/11052) will do the trick.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I agree that a Makefile is overkill, but it is nice to have a way to reconvert only the subset of modified files on subsequent runs. I've updated [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30420/11052) with a way to do that just with `find` so you don't have to resort to a Makefile.

Answer (score 2):

If you use only image files than maybe you would like to use **Comic Book Archive** (.cbr, .cbz, .cbt, .cba, .cb7)

- If you use 7Z then rename the file extension (suffix) to .cb7
- If you use ACE then rename the file extension (suffix) to .cba
- If you use RAR then rename the file extension (suffix) to .cbr
- If you use TAR then rename the file extension (suffix) to .cbt
- If you use ZIP then rename the file extension (suffix) to .cbz

This is much more flexible than PDF.

```
Under Linux you can use software like Comix, Evince, Okular and QComicBook.
```

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Comic_book_archive

Comment: downvoted, because it has nothing to do with the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

A tiny script would do the trick.
*(tested with ksh88 on Solaris 10)*

**script.ksh**

```
#!/bin/ksh

[[ $# != 1 ]] && exit 255 # test for nr of args

pdfname=$(sed -e 's/\(.*\)\.jpg/\1\.pdf/' <(echo $"1")) #replace *.jpg with *.pdf
convert "$1" $pdfname
```

Then you can run `find` to execute the script:

```
find dir -name image\*.jpg -exec /bin/ksh script.ksh {} \;
```

Note that both `script.ksh` and the `find` command I gave you, might have different syntaxes depeding on the OS and the shell you are using.

Comment: `pdfname=${1%.*}.pdf` replaces the file's extension with `pdf`. That method is a lot simpler and works even if the file name contains special characters. On a related note, add double quotes around variable substitutions.

Comment: There is no reason to write a separate script when it can all be done on the [with a simple single command line](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30420/11052).

Answer (score 1):

I got solve with imagemagick for conversion and parallel to accelerate my conversion process:

```
ls *.JPEG |parallel convert -density 200 -resize 496X646 -quality 100 {}  ../{.}.PDF
```

Answer (score 1):

**The MacOS utility `SIPS`**  Under MacOS (Sierra), Apple's built-in command-line utility `sips` provides comprehensive access to all of Apple's raster-image utilities; this turns out to include the conversion of `jpg` to `pdf`.

For example, from an existing low-resolution/small-size `jpg` image `'cat.jpg'` (of size 8401 bytes), the following command-line creates `'cat.pdf'`, with no change in raster-resolution and minimal expansion of file size:

```
$ sips -s format pdf cat.jpg --out 'cat.pdf' 1>/dev/null 2>&1
$ ls -l cat.*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 <user redacted> <group redacted>  8401 Jun 18 07:06 cat.jpg
-rw-r--r--+ 1 <user redacted> <group redacted> 10193 Jun 18 07:22 cat.pdf
```

**Conversion to Adobe's `PSD` raster-image format**  A similar `sips` idiom creates Adobe-compatible `*.psd` files

```
$ sips -s format psd cat.jpg --out 'cat.psd' 1>/dev/null 2>&1
$ ls -l cat.jpg cat.psd
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Administration  staff    8401 Jun 18 07:06 cat.jpg
-rw-r--r--+ 1 Administration  staff  350252 Jun 18 07:37 cat.psd
```

Note however the 30-fold file-size expansion that is attendant to the use of the Adope `psd` raster-format.

**Book Production**  In doing large-scale book production, involving hundreds of images, that are supplied in multiple formats, for me a convenient command-line idiom has been use `ImageMagick` utilities to create pure raster-image files in `png` format (with all meta-data and color profiles stripped-out), then use `sips` to restore a uniform set of color profiles and/or comments, and use `sips` also to generate final output files (most commonly `*.png`, `*.psd`, or `*.pdf` files).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately **`convert`** changes the image before so to have minimal loss of quality of the original `jpg` you need to use `img2pdf`, I use this commands:

1) This to make a `pdf` file out of every `jpg` image without loss of either resolution or quality:

```
ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
```

2) This to concatenate the `pdf`pages into one:

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
```

3) And last I add an OCRed text layer that doesn't change the quality of the scan in the pdfs so they can be searchable:

```
pypdfocr combined.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest way to convert multiple files is to go to the file directory in linux terminal and type:

```
$ convert *.png mypdf.pdf
```