# Argument list too long for ls

Tags: ls, arguments

I get the following error when trying to `ls *.txt | wc -l` a directory that contains many files:

```
-bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

Does the threshold of this "Argument list" dependent on distro or computer's spec?  Usually, I'd pipe the result of such big result to some other commands (`wc -l` for example), so I'm not concerned with limits of the terminal.

Comment: That counts as [parsing `ls`'s output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), which is a bad idea, so better avoid it. For counting see [What's the best way to count the number of files in a directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27493/whats-the-best-way-to-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory), for a tricky workaround see [why for loop doesn't raise “argument too long” error?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20681/why-for-loop-doesnt-raise-argument-too-long-error).

Comment: @manatwork Yes, I saw those questions, too.  Just wondering a better way to use or redirect a long output from a command in a more general fashion.

Comment: you can use getconf ARG_MAX to get the limit on most unix based systems

Comment: To count the files that match a pattern, use `set -- *.txt; printf 'There are %s .txt files\n' "$#"` instead.  This would give you the correct count regardless of whether a name contains newlines.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Your error message *argument list too long* comes from the ******* of `ls *.txt`.

This limit is a safety for both binary programs and your Kernel. See [ARG_MAX, maximum length of arguments for a new process](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/argmax/) for more information about it, and how it's used and computed.

There is no such limit on pipe size. So you can simply issue this command:

```
find -type f -name '*.txt'  | wc -l
```

NB: On modern Linux, weird characters in filenames (like newlines) will be escaped with tools like `ls` or `find`, but still displayed from *******. If you are on an old Unix, you'll need this command

```
find -type f -name '*.txt' -exec echo \;  | wc -l
```

NB2: I was wondering how one can create a file with a newline in its name. It's not that hard, once you know the trick:

```
touch "hello
world"
```

Comment: You don't need the `-exec echo \;`.

Comment: @ShawnJ.Goff I have tested it. There's no need of ` echo`  in current version of GNU find

Comment: @Coren @Mikel - not everybody has GNU's `find`.  The `find` on OS X and on busybox-based systems, and I would guess any BSD-based system shows the filename with a newline in it, which would mess with the count.

Comment: Huh?  `wc -l` is counting newlines.  So we *want* it to have newlines.

Comment: Oh, I see your point.  You don't want to print the file name at all, in case the file name itself contains a newline.  Fair enough.

Comment: All examples need a `-type f` to be correct too, I was going for clarity and simplicity.

Comment: Mac OSX doesn't like -type, this works though: `find . -name '*.txt' | wc -l`

Comment: @blak3r but `mkdir my_favourites.txt`

Answer (score 17):

It depends mainly on your version of the Linux kernel.

You should be able to see the limit for your system by running

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

which tells you the maximum number of bytes a command line can have after being expanded by the shell.

In Linux < 2.6.23, the limit is usually 128 KB.

In Linux >= 2.6.25, the limit is either 128 KB, or 1/4 of your stack size (see `ulimit -s`), whichever is larger.

See the [execve(2) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) for all the details.

---

Unfortunately, piping `ls *.txt` isn't going to fix the problem, because the limit is in the operating system, not the shell.

The shell expands the `*.txt`, then tries to call

```
exec("ls", "a.txt", "b.txt", ...)
```

and you have so many files matching `*.txt` that you're exceeding the 128 KB limit.

You'll have to do something like

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" | wc -l
```

instead.

(And see Shawn J. Goff's comments below about file names that contain newlines.)

Comment: Could you explain what the `.` and the `-maxdepth 1` mean in the last line? Thanks! :D

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé `.` means current directory, `-maxdepth 1` means it doesn't look in subdirectories.  This was intended to match the same files as `*.txt`.

Answer (score 14):

Another workaround:

```
ls | grep -c '\.txt$'
```

Even though `ls` produces more output than `ls *.txt` produces (or attempts to produce), it doesn't run into the "argument too long" problem, because you're not passing *any* arguments to `ls`.  Note that `grep` takes a regular expression rather than a file matching pattern.

You might want to use:

```
ls -U | grep -c '\.txt$'
```

(assuming your version of `ls` supports this option).  This tells `ls` not to sort its output, which could save both time and memory -- and in this case the order doesn't matter, since you're just counting files.  The resources spent sorting the output are usually not significant, but in this case we already know you have a very large number of `*.txt` files.

And you should consider reorganizing your files so you don't have so many in a single directory.  This may or may not be feasible.

Answer (score 2):

This might be dirty but it works for my needs and within my competency. I don't think it performs very quickly but it allowed me to get on with my day.

```
ls | grep jpg | <something>
```

I was getting a 90,000 long list of jpgs and piping them to avconv to generate a timelapse.

I was previously using ls *.jpg| avconv before I ran into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

MAX_ARG_PAGES appears to be a kernel parameter.  Using `find` and `xargs` is a typical combination to address this limit but I'm not sure it'll work for `wc`.

Piping the output of `find . -name \*\.txt` to a file and counting the lines in that file should serve as a workaround.

Comment: You can do anything with `ls`'s output, will not solve this. As long as the *.txt wildcard is expanded over the limit, will fail before even starting `ls` and generating any output.

Comment: True, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Better. But to make it a replacement for `ls` you should specify `-maxdepth 1` to avoid recursively scanning the subdirectories.