# How to do a loop to execute many files

Tags: shell-script, command-line

I have a script which function like this for one file.

```
./script 0001g.log > output
```

for two or more files, like this

```
./script 0001g.log 0002g.log 0003g.log > output
```

The script take one special number from each input file and put it in one output file.

My question is I have 1000 input files, how can I do a loop to execute my script.

Comment: you're going to have to express many more of the details of what you're trying to accomplish in hopes of getting any assistance.  to start with an obvious one, do the "log" files already exist? and if so, why doesn't this solve all your problems?:   ./script *.log > output

Comment: @Theophrastus the only reason I see not to use your solution is that `*.log` may be expanded over the `ARG_MAX` limit causing an `Argument list too long` [error](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38955/argument-list-too-long-for-ls). That being said, your approach is the best solution unless OP really faces this issue.

Comment: if it's just ARG_MAX holding you back, then 'find' should solve your problems (or find combined with xargs).  something akin to:   find . -type f -name '*.log' -exec ./script {} \;

Comment: In regards to: *The script take one special number from each input file and put it in one output file*, I have to wonder what your script actually does.  From the current description it sounds like you could be using a `grep` one-liner instead of a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few possible solutions:

Simply

```
$ ./script *g.log >output
```

... and hope that `*g.log` doesn't expand to something that makes the command line too long. This is not very robust.

If your script doesn't depend on the number of files given to it, i.e., if output can just be appended to `output` for each input file, then this is another solution:

```
$ find ./ -type f -name "*g.log" | xargs ./script >output
```

A third solution would be to move the loop into the script itself:

```
for f in *g.log; do
  # old code using "$f" as file name
done
```

This does not have the problem with command line length restriction since it's in a script.

The invocation of the script would now be

```
$ ./script >output
```

Answer (score 0):

if

```
./script 0001g.log 0002g.log 0003g.log > output
```

eq.

```
./script 0001g.log > output
./script 0002g.log >> output
./script 0003g.log >> output
```

then you can use loop or

```
`seq -f '%04gg.log' 10` | script > output
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  It looks like you have confused input with arguments.

Comment: This will try to use `0001g.log` as a command name. Also, it will exceed maximum command length for large values. (was going to write "for large values of 10")

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can put the files into a directory

```
/opt/location/source
    /0001g.log
    /0002g.log
    /0003g.log
```

Then in your bash script you can try the following

```
#!/bin/bash

# store path to files
SOURCE="/opt/location/source/"

# loop through files
for FILE in `ls $SOURCE*g.log`; do
    # do what you want to specific file
    echo $FILE
done
```

Comment: The OP has both script and files in the same directory (and possibly other thing too, we don't know). Your `for`-loop will process these too.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can be a bit more precise with what files you are listing

Comment: For the general case, if there was any file containing spaces or file globbing patterns in their file names, your loop would misbehave. Better to use `for FILE in $SOURCE/*g.log`.

Comment: that's good advice