# Bash script to sort files into alphabetical folders

Tags: bash, scripting

I try to organize my files and my folders by a script. It creates the folder with the first letter of my file and moves it there.

For the very first time, the script does the job, but if I create new files and execute the script again, it creates a new subfolder in the folder, and so on.

It creates, for example, `T/T/toto.txt`.

My script:

```
for first in $(ls -1 | sed 's/^\(.\).*$/\1/' | tr '[a-z0-9]' '[A-Z0-9]' | uniq)
do
    mkdir tmp
    mv "$first"* tmp/
    lower=$(echo $first | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
    mv "$lower"* tmp/
    mv tmp/ "$first";
done
```

Comment: I guess you rerun this script in the same folder you run it before. Therefore it will find the previously created directories and will move them as well.

Comment: You probably should add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line. Won't fix the problem but makes it clear you've written a `bash` script and not a `sh` one.

Answer (score 6):

Your script is picking up *directories* and non-directory files and moving these into subdirectories based on their names, even if they are the single-letter directories that we are sorting things into.  That's how the new directories appear. Your code also needlessly uses `sed` and `tr` etc., to do something that the `bash` shell can do quicker and safer. Additionally, `ls` should never be used in scripts for iterating over filenames (see, e.g. [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985) for why).

Another issue is that if you have many thousands of files with names starting with the same character, then the `mv "$first"* tmp/` command (or the second `mv`) may fail with an "argument list too long" error (see, e.g. [Argument list too long for ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38955) ; the issue applies to `mv` and all other external commands, not just `ls`).

An example script that works around these issues and that only uses functionality in `bash` apart from `mkdir` and `mv`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob  # makes the loop not loop at all if there are no files

for name in *; do
    if [[ -d $name ]] && [[ $name == ? ]]; then
        # skip directories that have single character names
        continue
    fi

    # get first character in filename
    first=${name:0:1}

    # compute destination directory name from this first
    # character by uppercasing it
    destdir=${first^}

    # make that directory if it does not already exist
    mkdir -p -- "$destdir"

    # move the file into place (name collisions not checked for)
    mv -- "$name" "$destdir"
done
```

The `--` options in the calls to `mkdir` and `mv` protect against filenames that may start with a dash (see, e.g. [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376)).

The main difference with this script is that I'm looping over the names in the directory rather than over the first characters, as you do.