# How to recursively search for *.mkv, *.avi, *.mp4 and replace with empty file with the same name

Tags: bash, files

Trying to get this working in CentOS and bash:

1. search for all mp4, mkv, avi recursively
2. delete that file and replace with empty file with the same name

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/449768). What's the larger picture/why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 7):

To find the files use `find`. To truncate the file use `truncate`. I am also using `xargs` to call upon `truncate`. However you could use the `-exec` option of `find` to avoid using `xargs`.

So something like this should work. (untested)

`find . \( -iname '*.mkv' -o -iname '*.avi' -o -iname '*.mp4' \) -print0 | xargs -0 echo truncate -s 0`

Remove the `echo` after testing that it outputs the correct commands, with correct file-names.

Comment: Although technically correct, combining find, xargs and truncate seems dangerous.
Anyone unfamiliar with any of those tools should further educate themselves before copy-pasting this. Building an equivalent of `rm -rf *` by accident is all too easy.

Comment: While the same generally applies to the globstar + loop approach from @terdon it seems to be much easier to reason about.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `globstar` option of bash which enables the `**` glob character:

```
globstar
    If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion con‐
    text will match all files and zero or  more  directories
    and  subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /,
    only directories and subdirectories match.
```

With that, you can use `**/*.mkv` to recursively find all files or directories whose name ends with `.mkv`. Next, don't think of this as deleting the original and creating a new file. All you need to do is empty the original file. The simplest way to do that is `> file`. That will open the file for writing, overwriting anything that was already there. Since you don't actually write anything, it will result in an empty file.

With that in mind, consider the following example:

```
$ tree -h
.
├── [4.0K]  dir1
│   ├── [4.0K]  subdir1
│   │   ├── [ 48K]  file.mp3
│   │   └── [ 53M]  file.mp4
│   └── [4.0K]  subdir2
│       └── [136M]  file2.avi
├── [4.0K]  dir2
│   ├── [399K]  file.mkv
│   └── [4.0K]  subdir1
│       └── [548M]  file3.avi
└── [ 30M]  file.avi

5 directories, 6 files
```

We have 6 files, 5 of which match the pattern you are looking for (`dir1/subdir1/file.mp3` should not be changed). To empty the files that match the pattern you gave, you just need to do this:

```
$ shopt -s globstar 
$ for f in **/*.mp4 **/*.avi **/*.mkv; do > "$f"; done
```

if we now run `tree` again, you will see that all files except the `mp3` one have been emptied:

```
$ tree -h
.
├── [4.0K]  dir1
│   ├── [4.0K]  subdir1
│   │   ├── [ 48K]  file.mp3
│   │   └── [   0]  file.mp4
│   └── [4.0K]  subdir2
│       └── [   0]  file2.avi
├── [4.0K]  dir2
│   ├── [   0]  file.mkv
│   └── [4.0K]  subdir1
│       └── [   0]  file3.avi
└── [   0]  file.avi
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `find` as ctrl-alt-delor suggested, but there's no need for `xargs` or `-print0` or any of that. Simply do:

```
find . \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mp4' \) -exec sh -c ' > "$1"' mysh {} \;
```

Comment: Won't globbing potentially result in a enormous (too long) command line?

Comment: @jippie hmm, yes it might, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: @jippie The "argument list too long" error is [not an issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20681/315749). The argument list may theoretically exceed the available virtual memory, but it's unlikely in practice (on my system, Bash needed ~330 MiB of memory to loop over a glob returning 1.5 million files).

Comment: FWIW, zsh is just fine with `:>**/*.{mkv,avi}`

Comment: @RomanOdaisky Not sure if zsh advanced features or emoticons.

Comment: @RomanOdaisky nice. Does it even need the `:`? If `: >` works, `>` should also work.

Comment: @terdon In zsh, bare `>f` is like `cat >f` and invites the user to type something that will end up as the content of the file(s).